# How to find this nice limit: $I=\lim_{t\to0^{+}}\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x,t)$

Tags: limits

Find the value:

> $$I=\lim_{t\to0^{+}}\lim_{x\to+\infty}\dfrac{\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\sqrt{t}}dx\int_{x^2}^{t}\sin{y^2}dy}{\left[\left(\dfrac{2}{\pi}\arctan{\dfrac{x}{t^2}}\right)^x-1\right]\arctan{t^{\frac{3}{2}}}}$$

I spent some hours doing it, but have failed.

Thank you!

Comment: 'nice limit' LOL

Comment: Just in case: are there is $\arctan (t^\frac{3}{2})$ or $(\arctan t)^\frac{3}{2}$?

Comment: Start by finding $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan\frac{x}{t^2}\right)^x$

Comment: @m0nhawk is $$\arctan{(t^{\frac{3}{2}})}$$

Comment: "Nice limit"...that sounded like old times' stories about the father inviting the unaware man to enter his house telling him "please do come in and meet my beautiful daughter"...and after the poor man met the girl he had to be hospitalized because the impression and horror hurt his weak heart...

Comment: HaHa. Thank you is good stroy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One observes
$$lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan\frac{x}{t^2}\right)^x = e^{lim_{x\to\infty}x\left(\ln\arctan\frac{x}{t^2}-\ln\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}.$$
In computing that limit I find:
$$lim_{x\to\infty}x\left(\ln\arctan\frac{x}{t^2}-\ln\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln\arctan\frac{x}{t^2}-\ln\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{1}{x}} =\\
= lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{\arctan\frac{x}{t^2}}\frac{1}{1+\frac{x^2}{t^4}}\frac{1}{t^2}}{-\frac{1}{x^2}} =
-lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2t^2}{\arctan\frac{x}{t^2}(t^4+x^2)} =
-\frac{2t^2}{\pi}$$

We can therefore find the original limit as
$$\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{\sqrt{t}\int_\infty^t\sin(y^2)dy}{\left(e^{-\frac{2t^2}{\pi}}-1\right)\arctan(t^{3/2})} =\\
= \lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}\int_\infty^t\sin(y^2)dy + \sqrt{t}\sin(t^2)}{-\frac{4t}{\pi}e^{-\frac{2t^2}{\pi}}\arctan(t^{3/2}) + \left(e^{-\frac{2t^2}{\pi}}-1\right)\frac{1}{1+t^3}\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{t}} =\\
= \lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{\frac{1}{2}\int_\infty^t\sin(y^2)dy + t\sin(t^2)}{-\frac{4t^{3/2}}{\pi}e^{-\frac{2t^2}{\pi}}\arctan(t^{3/2}) + \left(e^{-\frac{2t^2}{\pi}}-1\right)\frac{1}{1+t^3}\frac{3}{2}t}$$
and every term but the first one in the numerator tends to zero, so unless I've made some mistake (at this point it's more than likely--so let me know) the limit diverges.

Comment: I think $e^x-1\approx x,\arctan{x}\approx x$

Comment: @nanchangjian, I don't follow. Where's the error?